# Spark scala with dependencies in one single jar

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I have a Scala Spark application for which I want to create jar with dependencies using maven.

I am using maven-assembly-plugin

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

but when I am running my app with Spark-submit command, I am still getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. When I am running it with `--jars` option and provide path for dependencies jar, It is running fine. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thanks

Comment: Are you using the jar called 'jar-with-dependencies'? (We never know) What are the missing dependencies, Can you show your dependencies?

Comment: Sorry. my bad. I have given the dependency scope as 'provided' by mistake. So after removing the scope, My jar is working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The configuration looks good. 
Try to delete previous application jars and run ‘**mvn package**’ command to create a new one.